# Extjs templatecolumn is not computing data when it is hidden, can we make it compute data?

Tags: extjs

We are using templatecolumn of extjs to compute data and display that information elsewhere. The grid has few columns which are editable and after editing, the computation in templatecolumn happens. But when the templatecolumn is hidden, the data is not changing as change in the values of grid.

Column config for template column

```
{
    "xtype": "templatecolumn",
    "text": "Cases",
    "resizable": true,
    "draggable": false,
    "hidden": true,
    "hideMode": 'offsets', /** tried all hideMode - 'visibility, display and offsets' for resolving issue but not helped **/
    "width": 80,
    "align": "right",
    "cls": "clsPPFHeaderCols",
    "tdCls": "clsCells",
    "tpl": [
        "<tpl for='.'>",
        "{[getPlannerWorkAreaManager().getPerCases(undefined, values)]}",
        "</tpl>"
    ]
}
```

And function getPerCases has some calculation which involves other data from grid as well.

Comment: Can you attach the `computation` code ?

Comment: Can´t you create a "converted" field on the model instead? : { name: 'cases',  convert: function (value) {  return getPlannerWorkAreaManager().getPerCases(value); } }

Comment: Hi @FabioBarros, I used convert field in store.fields, it is working except for one issue. 
When I change value through editor, convert function triggered as expected, but when programmatically set values (record.set), then it is not getting triggered...
Anyways, you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: programmatically works for me, can you show how are you getting the record you are altering?

Comment: I just checked, no issues, calculate does trigger on setting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad it helps:
Create a "converted" field on the model instead using templatecolumn  :

```
  { 
     name:    'cases', 
     convert: function (value) { 
                  return getPlannerWorkAreaManager().getPerCases(value); 
              } 
  }
```